# Unable to download file in custome default directory path using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I'm using selenium==4.15.1 version and latest chrome web driver version 120.0.6099.71
unable to download file into specific download directory path instead it is downloading in system default downloads directory. But same code is working for another automation job and file is downloading in the specific downloading path.

```
def driver_conn(self, entity_tan,download_directory):
        tan_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Validation","CookieFiles",entity_tan)
        custom_tan_path = os.path.join(tan_path,"Default", "Cache")
        download_directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Validation", "DownloadFiles")
        try:
            os.mkdir(tan_path)
        except BaseException as e:
            logger.error("tan Folder exists")
        logger.info("custom dir path: {}".format(tan_path))

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        prefs = {
            "download.default_directory": download_directory,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
            "safebrowsing.enabled": False}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        options.add_experimental_option("detach",True)

        options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36")
        options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
        options.add_argument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows")
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+custom_tan_path)
        options.add_argument("--profile-directory="+entity_tan)
        
        options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'performance': 'ALL'})
        
                
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
            str1 = driver.capabilities['browserVersion']
            logger.info(str1)
            str2 = driver.capabilities['chrome']['chromedriverVersion']
            logger.info(str2)
            logger.info("Offline Webdriver found")
        except BaseException as e:
            logger.error("Webdriver error: {}".format(e))
        
        return driver
```

Comment: you may want to check for existence of the dir, and make it like you do with tan_path.  (If the folder doesn't exist, the browser will use default.)

Comment: Hi @pcalkins, we already have the directory created. even though the template from site is downloading into default download folder of the system instead of project folder. can you help on this.